# Conditional Switch clause?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

hey guys another TSQL question. I'm trying to only have one set of data listed instead of all the fields. Basically I need:

```
 If rep_name="MATT_RYAN" then switch to "Matt Ryan" else nothing
```

As of now, I get one row that works correctly, but I also have another row that lists all the other data from the other reps as well.

Thanks

Comment: Show sample data and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just hide whichever value is null on the table. I highlighted the row, and under properties I added this expression to the hidden value:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!EmptyValue.Value),True,False)
```